# How can I get the callback when Google Assistant command is triggered?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, android-tv, google-assistant-sdk

I have an Android cordova app which has Exoplayer Media Session enabled, the player was not resuming after seeking on AndroidTV using Google Assistant.

So I tried to save the `playWhenReady` on the `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady`(which is called when Google Assistant is opened) in a local property `wasPlaying`, to check if it should resume after seeking (if it was playing before).

```
private class MyControlDispatcher implements ControlDispatcher {

        private boolean wasPlaying = false;

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(Player player, boolean playWhenReady) {
            this.wasPlaying = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchSeekTo(Player player, int windowIndex, long positionMs) {
            if (this.wasPlaying) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            player.seekTo(windowIndex, positionMs);
            return true;
        }

        ...

    }
```

```
MyControlDispatcher myControlDispatcher = new MyControlDispatcher();
MediaSessionConnector mediaSessionConnector = new MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession);
mediaSessionConnector.setControlDispatcher(myControlDispatcher);
```

That solved the initial problem, but then I have a problem when user pauses and then seeks, both using Google Assistant. It will save `wasPlaying` as `true` when user calls `PAUSE` command (on the `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady` when assistant is opened) and resume after seeking when it shouldn't.

So basically I need to somehow get the `PAUSE` command callback from google assistant so I can differentiate from the `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady` which is called when assistant is opened. And guarantee that `wasPlaying` is set to `false` when user calls `PAUSE` command and prevent it from resuming after seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might handle these callbacks of MediaSessionCompat:

```
mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepare() {
                super.onPrepare();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareFromSearch(String query, Bundle extras) {
                super.onPrepareFromSearch(query, extras);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareFromMediaId(String mediaId, Bundle extras) {
                super.onPrepareFromMediaId(mediaId, extras);d
            }
})
```